# Error Using Post Twice?

Tags: php, html, post, paypal

because I am using PayPal and BlueSnap I have 2 different IPN's and seem to be having a Issue when they are both on the page, if I take one away then they will work really need this working spent hours trying to figure it out :/

```
<?php
    /**
     * If the player clicks the continue
     * button, it will perform the following
     * process. The process will redirect to
     * the checkout URL as long as the player
     * has entered their username details.
     */
    if (isset($_POST['continue'])) {
        $username = trim($_POST['username']);
        $product = trim($_POST['product']);
        if ($username != "Enter Username" && $username != "") {
            header("Location: http://www.plimus.com/jsp/buynow.jsp?contractId=" . $product . "&custom1=" . $username);
            exit;
        }
    }
?>
<html>

            <form action="<?php ?>" method="POST">
                <div name="select">
                    Product:
                    <select name="product">

                    </select>
                </div>
                <div name="username">
                    Username:
                    <input type="text" maxlength="12" name="username" value="Enter Username" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Enter Username';" onfocus="if(this.value=='Enter Username') this.value='';"/>
                </div>
                <?php
                    /**
                     * If the user enters their username details
                     * incorrectly, it will perform this process.
                     * This will just send a line of text asking
                     * them to enter their username. I recommend
                     * carrying over this process when you integrate
                     * it with your own website theme.
                     */
                    if (isset($_POST['continue']))
                        echo "<font color=red>Please enter your username.</font>";
                ?>
                <div name="button">
                    <button type="submit" name="continue" value="Continue">Continue</button>
                </div>
            </form>
<a href="http://www.plimus.com/ecommerce/buyers" target="_blank" title="Trusted and Secure Online Payment Processing via PLIMUS"><img src="https://www.plimus.com/images/icons_wizard/icons/cards/cards_type2_1-1.gif" border="0"></a>
            </center>

            <br>

            <br>
<center>
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $errors = array();

        $user = trim($_POST['user']);
        $prod = trim($_POST['prod']);
        header("Location: paypal.php?username=". $user ."&prod=". $prod);
        exit;
    }

?>

    <form action="<?php echo basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="POST">
    <tr><td><center>
        <table>
            <select name="prod">


            </select> </td></tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Username:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="user" value="" /></td> <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></td> 
            </tr>
            </table>
            </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're storing the processed data into some form of database.
What I would do is store the data as you normally would, then run a quick select to make sure there's no double submission.
This is also assuming you've sanitized/validated the POSTDATA

```
$check = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT `id` FROM `ipn_data` WHERE `txn_id` = '".$_POST['txn_id']."'");
if(mysqli_num_rows($check))
    exit("You've already submitted this payment");
mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO `ipn_data` (`custom`, `txn_id`) VALUES (".$_POST['custom'].", '".$_POST['txn_id']."')");
```

Something along those lines.
I can provide my paypal IPN class upon request

`<form action="someaction.php" name="paypal" method="post">` and
`<form action="someaction.php" name="plimus" method="post">`
then simply running a check to see which form was posted:
`if(isset($_POST['paypal']))` and
`if(isset($_POST['plimus']))`

Comment: It's not that I wan't this is just the page where you select you're items you want to purchase and because I used the "post" method twice I can't have them on the same page as you can see here http://boomscape.co.uk/donate.php & here is my paypal donate page http://boomscape.co.uk/donatepp.php when they are together the paypal one no longer works :S

Comment: Ah, I see. Have you tried naming the forms differently?
`<form action="someaction.php" name="paypal" method="post">` and `<form action="someaction.php" name="plimus" method="post">` then simply running a check to see which form was posted: `if(isset($_POST['paypal']))` and `if(isset($_POST['plimus']))`

I'll update my original post due to the formatting on comments not being great

Comment: I tried that didn't work man :/ It's so annoying having to use 2 different pages for my stuff :/

Comment: How strange.. Another option would be to name the submit button and check which "submit" was submitted.

Comment: It's not the submit button as I used both of them with different names it's to do with the Post I am 100% sure as I named it to POST1 which made the page put ?variableshere so idk :/